# Looping a rep() function in r

Tags: r, for-loop

`df` is a frequency table, where the values in `a` were reported as many times as recorded in column `x,y,z`. I'm trying to convert the frequency table to the original data, so I use the **rep()** function.

How do I loop the `rep()` function to give  me the original data for x, y, z without having to repeat the function several times like I did below?

Also, can I input the result into a data frame, bearing in mind that the output will have different column lengths:

```
a <- (1:10)
x <- (6:15)
y <- (11:20)
z <- (16:25)
df <- data.frame(a,x,y,z)
df
rep(df[,1], df[,2])
rep(df[,1], df[,3])
rep(df[,1], df[,4])
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to repeat the for loop, you can always try using an `apply` function. Note that you cannot store it in a `data.frame` because the objects are of different lengths, but you could store it in a list and access the elements in a similar way to a `data.frame`. Something like this works:

```
df2<-sapply(df[,2:4],function(x) rep(df[,1],x))
```

What this `sapply` function is saying is for each column in `df[,2:4]`, apply the `rep(df[,1],x)` function to it where `x` is one of your columns ( `df[,2]`, `df[,3]`, or `df[,4]`).

The below code just makes sure the apply function is giving the same result as your original way.

```
 identical(df2$x,rep(df[,1], df[,2]))
[1] TRUE
 identical(df2$y,rep(df[,1], df[,3]))
[1] TRUE
 identical(df2$z,rep(df[,1], df[,4]))
[1] TRUE
```

**EDIT:**

If you want it as a `data.frame` object you can do this:

```
res<-as.data.frame(sapply(df2, '[', seq(max(sapply(df2, length)))))
```

Note this introduces `NA`s into your `data.frame` so be careful!

Comment: thank you @MikeyMike. that did the trick. But how do i convert the output into a dataframe that i can work with while retaining the data in the respective columns.

Comment: i tried using data.frame(matrix(unlist(df), ncol=37, by row=T)) and it just gives me a matrix without the putting the values of x, y and z under the appropriate columns.

Comment: since they are of different lengths, are you OK with having NAs in your columns?

Comment: I dont mind the NAs. they will be omitted in further analysis